# Check if value exists in firebase DB

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a method in firebase, which can check if value exist in DB? Firebase has method [.exists()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#exists), but according to docs it checks only the keys.

I have the following structure:

```
{
  "users": {
    "-KKUmYgLYREWCnWeHCvO": {
      "fName": "Peter",
      "ID": "U1EL9SSUQ",
      "username": "peter01"
    },
    "-KKUmYgLYREWCnWeHCvO": {
      "fName": "John",
      "ID": "U1EL5623",
      "username": "john.doe"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to check if ID with value `U1EL5623`exists.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The `exists()` method is part of the `snapshot` object which is returned by firebase queries. So **keep in mind that you won't be able to avoid retrieving the data to verify if it exists or not**.

```
ref.child("users").orderByChild("ID").equalTo("U1EL5623").once("value",snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.exists()){
      const userData = snapshot.val();
      console.log("exists!", userData);
    }
});
```

---

### Observations:

In case you are in a different scenario which you have the exact ref path where the object might be, you wont need to add `orderByChild` and `equalTo`. In this case, you can fetch the path to the object directly so it wont need any search processing from firebase. Also, **if you know one of the properties the object must have you can do as the snippet below and make it retrieve just this property and not the entire object. The result will be a much faster check.**

```
//every user must have an email
firebase.database().ref(`users/${userId}/email`).once("value", snapshot => {
   if (snapshot.exists()){
      console.log("exists!");
      const email = snapshot.val();
   }
});
```

Comment: how you can do this with angularfire2 ??

Comment: @Xvegas you can do it similarly like this:

`const dbRef = this.db.database.ref();
dbRef.child(childName).orderByChild(objKey).equalTo(keyToCheck).once('value', snapshot => { // your code here });`

The `orderByChild` part is very important. It didn't work for me without it.

Comment: how do I search if the key "ID" is not known?

Comment: @Nikhil Not known or dynamic? If you don't know which key you are looking for you won't be able to check if it exists or not.

Comment: so what I mean is inside of the topic "KKUmYgLYREWCnWeHCvO", I want to search for any value say "Peter". I don't care which key matches

Comment: @adolfosrs Do you know if it's possible to limit the query to the documents that have a particular field? Say, only documents where document.completed exists?

Comment: @Pim Is `completed` a boolean property? If so you could just use `orderByChild('completed').equalTo(true)`

Comment: @adolfosrs It's not a boolean unfortunately

Comment: How do you handle the event where the value does not exist? @adolfosrs?

Comment: @DerryckDX Would you please elaborate on that? In case the value does not exist the `exists()` would return `false`. You could open a new question here in SO with an example and more details to address that better :)

Comment: @adolfosrs That's exactly what I was looking for. I needed to check if an email exists in the users collection.

Comment: "So keep in mind that you won't be able to avoid retrieving the data to verify if it exists or not", isn't it the same as just doing a "find" in js on the front end if you pull the data anyways? @adolfosrs

Comment: I like this method of searching for the data faster than getting the whole object. nice answer

Comment: @FabricioG Sorry, not sure if I get what you meant.

Comment: @adolfosrs As this is a good duplicate target, please consider appending the modern JavaScript SDK syntax to the answer. Alternatively, I can edit it into your answer with your go-ahead.

Comment: @samthecodingman sure mate, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: @samthecodingman roled it back since the question clearly lost traction after the edits

Comment: Fair enough. Worst case scenario, they can [look at that revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37910159/11) for the updated syntax.

Answer (score 3):

This is a similar solution if you want to check if an email exists in firebase

```
firebase.app().database().ref("shops").orderByChild("email")
   .equalTo(user.email).once("value", snapshot => {

            const userData = snapshot.val();

            // Check if it is a SHOP.
            if (userData) {
              console.log("Shop logged in!");
              this.setState({
                isAdminLoggedIn: false,
                isUserLoggedIn: false,
                isShopLoggedIn: true,
                isNoneLoggedIn: false
              });

            // Check if it is a USER.
            } else {
              console.log("User logged in");
              this.setState({
                isAdminLoggedIn: false,
                isUserLoggedIn: true,
                isShopLoggedIn: false,
                isNoneLoggedIn: false
              });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't make comments yet, so I'm posting an answer:

To add to the suggested answer, if you wanted to query whether or not any users exist, you can try to improve performance by adding .limitToFirst(1) or .limitToLast(1). This way you can limit your retrieved data to the minimum:

```
//Check if any users exist
firebase.database().ref(`users`).limitToFirst(1).once("value", snapshot => {
   if (snapshot.exists()){
      console.log("exists!");
      // TODO: Handle that users do exist
      return true;
   }

   // TODO: Handle that users do not exist
});
```

sources: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#limitToFirst

Answer (score 1):

This is how I searched for a url value in Firebasebase database on my project:

```js
const searchFirebase = (url, idx) => 
{
     firebase
       .app()
       .database()
       .ref("recipes")
       .orderByChild("url")
       .equalTo(url)
       .once("value", (snapshot) => {
         if (snapshot.exists()) {
           const userData = snapshot.val();
           console.log("exists!", userData);
           document.querySelector(`[data-recipe-id="${idx}"]`)
           .classList.replace('fav-heart', 'unfav-heart'); 
         } else {
           return false; 
         }
       });
}
```