# How to filter element by its children value with Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a collection called `users`, it its filled with elements(users) named by their Firebase uids, ex:

```
users/1k239k1293k01k923
```

Lets suppose I need to retrieve an user (or all users) which have the atribute `provider == "facebook"`.

Something like `users/$someuser/provider == "facebook"`

The problem is I don't know what user will match this atribute.

**I'm using Javascript SDK** (web)

Comment: You should use [`orderByChild`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#orderByChild) and [`equalTo`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#equalTo)

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37910008/check-if-value-exists-in-firebase-db/37910159#37910159) will help you to work it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Firebase [documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/) are very good, I would advise to do some reading there.

JS:

```
// Provider
var provider = "facebook";
// Find all users with certain provider
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
    ref.orderByChild("provider").equalTo(provider).on("value", function(snapshot) {
    // iterate through each match
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        // key will be "ada" the first time and "alan" the second time
        var key = childSnapshot.key;
        // childData will be the actual contents of the child
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
     });
});
```

This is a combination of `orderByChild`, `equalTo` and `forEach`. The `forEach` is used to iterate through each match and do whatever you want from there.

The `.on("value"` can be changed to `.once("value`, `.on("child_added`, etc..

Comment: thank you. However, I don't think Google know how to document their stuff.