# Set error if value already exists in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to set error in Edittext if mobile number already exists in the Firebase database. If the user enters the existed number the values gets updated so anyone can give existed number and change the data. I want to display Toast or error if mobile already exist.

[image]

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
        String location = actv.getText().toString();
        String dob = age.getText().toString();
        String name1 = name.getText().toString();
        String mobile1 = mobile.getText().toString();
        String blood1 = blood.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String combo = name1 + "," + mobile1 + "," + location + "," + dob;

        if (blood1.equals("") || mobile1.equals("") ||  location.equals("Tap to detect") || dob.equals("") ) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please fill all the details.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {


            mFirebaseDatabase.child("users").child(blood1).child(mobile1).setValue(combo);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Donor Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent home = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class);
            startActivity(home);
            finish();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37910008/check-if-value-exists-in-firebase-db. If you're having trouble making that work, edit your question to include the code that you already tried.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have added a second duplicate as I saw that the OP has edited the question to add Java code. The first duplicate is in Javascript, so I hope is more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Alex! Will we see you in Madrid in a few weeks?

Comment: I've updated the question. Resolution would be appreciated. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: What happens if you run the code in a debugger and put a breakpoint on `if (blood1.equals("")...`? What are the values of `blood1`, `mobile1` and `location`? Then where does the debugger go if you step through the code from there?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It goes to mobile1 and so on as in the picture updated above. I'm new to android what should i do now. i just want to check mobile number already existed in db. thanks

Comment: None of the code that is currently in your questions *reads* anything from the database, so it can't be checking for duplicates. The questions Alex and I linked show how to check for duplicates.