# Check if value is already in firebase database (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have such a code to check if value already exists in firebase database:

```
private boolean nameIsValid(final String input) {
    final boolean[] valid = {true};

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot:snapshot.getChildren()) {
                if(dataSnapshot.child(input).exists()) {
                    valid[0] = false;
                } 
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

    return valid[0];
}
```

It should return true if value does not exist and return false otherwise. But, unforchunatelly, it does not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if value exists in firebase DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37910008/check-if-value-exists-in-firebase-db)

Comment: @EdwardRomero no, unfortunatelly. I think I did everything as this answer says, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please check the first duplicate answer to see how you can check a user for existence and the second to see how you can use a callback to get the data from Firestore because you cannot return that value as a result of a method.