# Check If There Are Any Values in FireBase RealTime DataBase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database that looks like this:

[image]

I want to check if a 'Data' Child Exists.

I have a start:

```
var check = firebase.database().ref().orderByKey().equalTo("data").once("value", function (snapshot) {
if (!snapshot.exists()) { 
    firebase.database().ref('data').set({
        messages: [],
        userIds: [],
        colours: [],
        names: [],
    });
}
```

});

I don't know what to put in the `ref()` function

Comment: Have you checked [Check if value exists in Firebase db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37910008/check-if-value-exists-in-firebase-db) ?

Comment: I have checked it, and it doesn't really help. I have fixed my question with my work so far

Comment: It's worth also mentioning that writing an empty array to the RTDB won't actually write anything because there is no data to write. An empty array is just that, empty. The RTDB will remove any empty objects from the database entirely. In addition, [arrays should be avoided](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much simpler than what you're trying:

```
var check = firebase.database().ref("data");
check.once("value", function (snapshot) {
  if (!snapshot.exists()) { 
    ...
  }
});
```